# Getting another app's pushes text in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way how I can read pushes for another app at the moment they arrive to device in my own app? I want to get their full text to parse it and use immediately(after about 30 seconds it becomes useless)

Comment: It may be possible on a jail broken device, I don't know, but you can't do this on I modified iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, luckily this is not possible. As a user I would definitely not want this!

An APNs is bound to a device and an app, for more information consult the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).